# Finding common elements in matrices of different size

Tags: matlab, set-intersection

I have a two differently-sized matrices, for example:

```
A = [10 12 15 16 17 43 77];
B = [10 11 15 20 43 55 222 90 86];
```

I want to compare these two matrices to find out the same values and store them in a new variable. The result should look like this:

```
C = [10 15 43];
```

As I am new user of MATLAB, it would be nice if anyone gave me ideas regarding this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the similar values that are also in the same position or just similar values?

Answer (score 5):

If the size of the 2 arrays are the same, simply do:

```
C = find(A==B);
```

It finds all elements satisfying the test `A==B`; that test is performed element-wise: the output is a mask of the same size of the input arrays where each element is true if `A(i)==B(i)`.

For non-equally sized array, a solution is to call the function `intersect`:

```
C = intersect(A,B);
```

It does exactly what you want, getting the common values in A and B. Note that the output values are sorted. As stated by [excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza) in comments, it is possible to get the common values in the same order as they appear in the first array passed in argument (`A` in this example), by adding the option `'stable'` to the call:

```
C = intersect(A,B,'stable');
```

Comment: My arrays are not same size. That is the problem @Bentoy13

Comment: Passing the [`'stable'` `setOrder` parameter to `intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html?refresh=true#inputarg_setOrder) returns the values in the same order as A. It also might be worth clarifying what you mean by 'element-wise' for the  `find` approach, it's intuitive to those familiar with array operations but not necessarily to newer users.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Bentoy13's solution would be to use the function `ismember`:

```
C = A(ismember(A,B))
```

It basically takes the values of A that are in B.

Comment: I don't know how this got a downvote, it's completely right